# MVC5 model collection data type

Tags: c#, list, collections, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I have coded a C# MVC5 internet application, and I have a question about the model structure when dealing with a list.

I have a `MapCompany` class and a `MapLocation` class. The `MapCompany` class has a `List<MapLocation>`.

When I create a `MapLocation` and I add this to a `MapCompany`, and save this to the database, when I retrieve the `MapCompany` at a later stage, the list of `MapLocation` is empty.

Rather than using a `List<MapLocation>`, do I need to use another collection type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please paste some code here? Your question is not 100% clear to me and adding code would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. All I needed was the virtual keyword for the list in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell from the code here but the line that comments out the addition to mapcompanies.mapLoations.add(...)

1) does the save actually populate the mapLocations object in the database.
2) unless you do an include to pull in related entities, related entities are lazy loaded so would not appear until you reference the data.

Comment: 1. Yes, the MapLocation is added to the database. Whenever I ask for the MapCompany that the MapLocation is added to however, the List of MapLocations has a count of 0.

Comment: Also, is the same result achieved by these two lines of code: db.mapCompanies.Where(c => c.Id == mapCompanyId).First().mapLocations.Add(maplocation); and mapcompany.mapLocations.Add(maplocation);

Comment: I have figured it out Mike. All I needed was the virtual keyword for the list.